# What does the `tools:replace` attribute do in an Android Manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have found a few questions about bugs regarding `tools:replace`, but nowhere on the internet about what it does.

I did find the [tools attributes reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes), it seems like this is an outdated attribute that is no longer documented.

Can someone explain what it does? For example,
`tools:replace="android:label,android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup">` is found as an attribute of the `application` tag. In the same `application` xml tag, there is `android:label`, `android:supportsRtl` and `android:allowBackup` specified, so I can only **guess** that it will override these attributes if they are specified in `activity` tags nested inside `application` tag. This feature would seem useless, as I would expect `application` attributes to, by default set its children's attributes if they are not set.

Edit: thanks for linking [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#attribute_markers) in your answer. Personally I think the docs are quite comprehensive, which even provides examples as to when you would use this. Unfortunately my search engine failed to find this for me. This link was actually first on Google, but missing on DuckDuckGo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tools:replace` is an attribute marker which can be used to [reconfigure](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge) the main manifest file by merging specific manifest setups from project [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) (build variants).

Let's say you have the next node in the main manifest, where a specific Activity is defined as exported:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.ActivityTest"
    android:exported="true"> 
    ...
```

But for a specific flavor (build variant), the same Activity shouldn't be exported. So, you define a barebone manifest file within the flavor folder, and add the node with the replacement attribute:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.ActivityTest"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:replace="android:exported"> 
    ...
```

When selecting the target flavor in **Active Build Variant**, the build system will merge both manifests, and replace in the main manifest node the `android:exported` attribute with flavor's one.

To summarize, you use this attribute marker when you have multiple project flavors, and each need to define different attributes for existing nodes defined in the main manifest file.

Notice that you can also replace a full node completely by adding instead `tools:node="replace"`.